# Error creating class in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

Hi there I´m using enterprise architect. I configure a server connected to my ODBC MySQL, and import data works like a charm. But every time that I try to add or edit a class in the Class model page, I receive this error:

```
   enterprise architect class row cannot be located for updating some values may have been changes since it was last read
```

Any idea what it´s about?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the wrong MySQL odbc driver version or settings. Check the manual at http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.0/projects_and_teams/setupmysqlodbcdriver.html